# node.js watch the folder and run script

Tags: node.js, pm2, nodemon

I newb in node.js
In my project I use PM2 to restart node.js and it works fine.

But, I need to watch folder for changes, start script and not restart it after exit.

For simplicity I use yml for I18n.
My goal, when I make changes in yml file, run script to convert it to json and that's all.
Wait until new changes in yml file.

PM2 works, but it tries restart script again and again after each
exit.

> PM2        | App [i18n compile] with id [1] and pid [28803], exited
>   with code [0] via signal [SIGINT] PM2        | Script
>   /home/.../src/i18n/convert.js had too many unstable
>   restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"

May be I should use another tool for this issue?

Answer (score 7):

`nodemon` is a tool that will allow you to make a change to a file in a directory and automatically run a script

nodemon can be installed by `npm install -g nodemon`

executing `nodemon script.js` will automatically run `node script.js` when there is either a change to `script.js` or to any other file within the same directory as `script.js`

Comment: And how to bind it with ES6?

node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/i18n/convert.js

yarn babel-node  -- nodemon src/i18n/convert.js

yarn babel-node  -- node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/i18n/convert.js

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: if you have a newer version of node installed (iirc node >= 7.6.0) es6 functionality will work

Comment: can you electorate? do you mean require? are you using babel?

Comment: Yes, I use babel.

Comment: the argument(s) that should be passed to nodemon will be the same as what you pass to node in order to run your script

Answer (score 1):

I reminded to myself that live in async environment:

1. Wrote own watcher.
2. Added locales dir to PM2 ignore_watch in main app.
3. Added my watcher as PM2 app, but watching only to watcher.

---

```
{
  name         : 'I18n compiler',
  interpreter  : 'babel-node',
  script       : 'tools/locales.watcher.js',
  cwd          : path.root,
  watch        : 'tools/locales.watcher.js',
  ignore_watch : ['config', 'src', 'server', 'package.json'],
  env: {
    NODE_PATH: path.src,
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
  },
}
```

---

```
import fs      from 'fs';
import config  from '../config/general';
import convert from 'i18n/convert.js';

const { path } = config;

 // Synchronous recursively list files in a directory
function getFilesRecur(dir, filelist) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  filelist = filelist || [];
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory()) {
      filelist = getFilesRecur(path.join(dir, file), filelist);
    } else if ((/\.(yml|yaml)$/i).test(file)) {
      filelist.push(path.join(dir, file));
    }
  });
  return filelist;
}

export default function setupLocalesWatcher(){
  const files = getFilesRecur(path.i18n);

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(`Watching: ${file}`);
    fs.watchFile(file, () => {
      convert(file);
    });
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node now has a `--watch` flag (experimental at moment)

```
node --watch index.js
```

you can read more about it and its options in the docs here:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cli.html#--watch